# Получение координат лица через Camera API 2

Tags: android-sdk, android-camera

В `Android SDK` через `Camera API 2` можно получить координаты лица.

Относительно каких размеров получаются эти координаты? Т.е при инициализации камеры я назначаю размер предпросмотра:

```
surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)
```

но размеры лица получается явно не относительно этого размера. Собственно, относительно какого размера получаются размеры лица?

Answer (score 1):

[Из документации:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/Face.html#getBounds())

> A rectangle relative to the sensor's CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE, with (0,0) representing the top-left corner of the active array rectangle.

Можно посмотреть другие ответы на SO ([здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712770/3422245), например)

Comment: Вру, не то, это для API 1, для API 2 такое не работает(

Comment: Извините, поправил ответ, оказалось все намного сложнее :(